# Multiple UICollectionViews in one ViewController

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, xcode8, uistoryboard

Im having some trouble wrapping my head around how to Incorporate **TWO UICollectionViews within the same UIViewController / UITableViewController**, WHILE allowing them to **Scroll Vertically Together**.

**View Demo Image Here:**

[image: Instagram App Layout]

I have managed to replicate the above styling and positioning for my mobile app, but here is my dilemma:

- The Top UICollectionView Scrolls **Horizontally**
- The Bottom UICollectionView Scrolls **Vertically**

What I want to achieve is for them to scroll vertically together, and the Above CollectionView to scroll Horizontally on its own.

How would you achieve this? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Use one UICollectionView that has its first item as a UICollectionView, that should achieve the desired effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one collectionview(which scrolls vertically) inside your view controller.
Check out how to implement  the following delegate method

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
```

This delegate method can be used to have a custom view at the top ( header view for collection view)
Inside that header view you can have your second collectionview(the one which scrolls horizontally)

I Have implemented the same thing in this app

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/baetter-poll-on-the-go/id1134956263?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

you need to set two UIcollectionview with different names.First add for horizontally scroll and second vertically scroll.

At the time of collection view datasource and delegate methods call check collectionview by names.

I think it's just simple.

If you facing other problem let me know.